# O que é uma gajaderopa?

Tags: expressões, vocabulário

Segundo o [priberam, uma gajaderopa é um pé-de-burro](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Gajaderopa), que é uma "espécie de marisco"...

No entanto, no [lexico.pt, o pé-de-burro é uma planta bulbosa](http://www.lexico.pt/pe-de-burro/), conhecida como açafrão bravo (também no [wikcionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9-de-burro)).

Por isso, para não criar ambiguidades, o que é uma *gajaderopa*? Não consegui identificar corretamente nos motores de busca, mas supostamente será um [bivalve](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bivalve), visto que a própria expressão se refere a uma [*gaja*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gaja) (calão de mulher) vestida ou coberta por roupa.

Comment: Não conhecia sequer essa palavra.

Comment: @JorgeB. encontrei-a nas palavras relacionadas do priberam, presumo que seja algo comum junto de comunidades piscatórias (ou seja, suficientemente popular para lhe ser dada entrada no dicionário).

Comment: `No entanto, no lexico.pt` - como assim, "no entanto"? No lexico.pt [gajaderopa também é um marisco](http://www.lexico.pt/gajaderopa/)...

Comment: @ANeves bem apanhado, esqueceram-se de adicionar  a [gajaderopa](http://www.lexico.pt/gajaderopa/) no [pé-de-burro](http://www.lexico.pt/pe-de-burro/).

Answer (score 5):

No [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gajaderopa) *gajaderopa* é definida como

> Espécie de marisco, conhecido também por pé-de-burro.

Outras referências ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Gajaderopa), [Lexico.pt](http://www.lexico.pt/gajaderopa/), [Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/gajaderopa/)) definem *gajaderopa* da mesma maneira.

Pela maneira como a pergunta foi formulada, parece que a definição de pé-de-burro causou uma confusão, pois não menciona *gajaderopa* como um sinônimo, ao menos no [Lexico.pt](http://www.lexico.pt/pe-de-burro/) e no [Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/pe-de-burro/) (no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%A9-de-burro) o sinônimo aparece corretamente).

Comment: Sim, não sei se por lapso ou propositadamente... O priberam é o único dicionário até agora que diz que um _pé-de-burro_ é uma _gajaderopa_ (nem mencionam a planta). Seria mesmo interessante perceber qual a espécie de marisco que representa.

Comment: @Armfoot Se entendi bem, os pés-de-burro são os que estão ao centro [nesta foto](http://imagens.publico.pt/imagens.aspx/508823?tp=KM&w=460&h=305&act=Resize). Ver também [isto](http://www.josemanuelprata.pt/PT/index.asp?menuID=2).

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado! É realmente a melhor referência até agora. Coloquei a [informação em baixo](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/821/156), caso o site deixe de existir.

Answer (score 3):

Graças ao [bfavaretto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/818/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-gajaderopa/819?noredirect=1#comment2036_819), que descobriu um link de uma empresa ligada ao comércio de peixes e mariscos com um [compêndio de várias espécies de mariscos](http://www.josemanuelprata.pt/PT/index.asp?menuID=2), existe a referência a:

> ### [Pé-de-Burrinho](http://www.josemanuelprata.pt/PT/index.asp?menuID=8&show=17)
>
> [image: fotografia de um pé-de-burrinho] **Espécie**: Chamelea gallina; **Tamanho**: mínimo 2,5 cm
>
> Habita em fundos de areia e lodo na zona intermarés até à profundidade de 20m. Possui
>   concha sólida, equivalve e inequilateral. Possui uma forma oval
>   triangular, espessa e brilhante. Vértices pequenos e inclinados para
>   o bordo anterior. Ligamento estreito pouco extenso. Lúnula curta com
>   finas linhas concêntricas. Escultura com costelas concêntricas um
>   pouco irregulares, muito juntas e arredondadas. Margens internas
>   crenuladas abaixo do umbo até a margem posterior do escudo.
>
> Possui três dentes cardinais em cada valva e não possui dentes laterais. O
>   seio paleal é triangular e curto. Cor geralmente branca ou acastanhada
>   apresentando bandas radiais normalmente castanhas. Nalguns espécimenes
>   a concha pode ser azul ou verde. Interior branco podendo ser machado
>   de violáceo junto ao umbo.

Porém, existe outra espécie que tem exatamente o mesmo nome:

> ### [Pé-de-Burro](http://www.josemanuelprata.pt/PT/index.asp?menuID=8&show=18)
>
> [image: fotografia de um pé-de-burro] **Espécie**: Venus verrucosa;
>   **Tamanho**: mínimo 4 cm
>
> Habita todo o tipo de fundos, mas principalmente os de areia grossa. Possui concha sólida, equivalve e
>   inequilateral de forma oval arredondada. Possui uma escultura com
>   fortes estrias concêntricas que se tornam tuberculosas junto aos
>   bordos anterior e posterior formando pequenos nódulos.
>
> O escudo estende-se na valva esquerda. Linhas de crescimento pouco visiveis.
>   Lúnula lanceolada bem definida. Possui margens internas ligeiramente
>   crenuladas excepto abaixo do escudo. Cada valva tem três dentes
>   cardinais e nenhum lateral. O seio paleal é pequeno e de forma
>   triangular. De cor creme podendo apresentar bandas radias castanhas ou
>   rosadas.

Até ao momento, isto parece ser a fonte mais fidedigna das espécies que poderão ser consideradas como *gajaderopa*.

Uma pequena dedução da minha parte: as estrias concêntricas fazem realmente lembrar uma saia folhada de várias camadas, talvez daí a origem da expressão.

Comment: tens certeza que gajaderopa é este _pé-de-burrinho_ e não o _pé-de-burro_ existente na mesma página?

Comment: @gmauch foi isso que estive a editar :) obrigado.